# I want to implement websocket using java but getSessionAttributes() function referenced by StompHeaderAccessor is showing error

Tags: java, websocket, stomp

I was using this code block. But the getSessionAttributes() was showing error. I used library "spring-messaging.jar-4.0.0 Release". I found on their website that this function exists in this class. But the library I've used doesn't contain this class. How can this be solved? I cannot update the class file and add the function!

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                           SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    // Add username in web socket session
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
    return chatMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the library version. Every reference blog on the internet suggested `spring-messaging.jar-4.0.0 Release.jar`. But this library version was old. So, I just needed a newer version. I added `"spring-messaging.jar-4.1.\* Release.jar"`. Now the problem is resolved.

Comment: Could you mark your question as resolved, for posterity ?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You should have a button on the left of your answer.

Comment: Answers can be marked as solved after 2 days of posting the question. I'll mark it as resolved tomorrow.